# Modulus Behavior -1 % 3 (C++)

Tags: c++, modulo

```
if (currIndex < 0) {

            cout << currIndex << " % " << array.size() << endl;

            currIndex = currIndex % array.size();

            cout << currIndex << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
-1 % 3
0
```

-1 % 3 = -1 in C++ so why is 0 being returned?

Full Snippet:
https://ideone.com/leWqhi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

size() returns unsigned integer type, so this computation is done by casting -1 to unsigned and performing unsigned modulo.

Cast size() to signed integer type to get correct result.